# Thrust+boost code compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, thrust

I have strange problem which I can't solve. It's connected with boost+thrust code.

Code:

```
#include <boost/config/compiler/nvcc.hpp>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/detail/type_traits.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <common/inc/helper_cuda.h>

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/operation.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/system.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/command_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/algorithm/generate.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/algorithm/generate_n.hpp>


#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
using namespace boost::random;
using namespace boost::compute;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N = 100000;

    unbounded_array<float> lineMatrix1(N*N);
    unbounded_array<float> lineMatrix2(N*N);    

    generate_n(lineMatrix1.begin(), N*N, []() { return (10 * rand() / RAND_MAX); });
    generate_n(lineMatrix2.begin(), N*N, []() { return (10 * rand() / RAND_MAX); });    

    matrix<float> matrix1(N, N, lineMatrix1);
    matrix<float> matrix2(N, N, lineMatrix2);
    matrix<float> zeroMatrix(N, N, 0);  
    matrix<float> zeroMatrix2(N, N, 0);

    //boost single core computation start

    auto matrix3 = prod(matrix1, matrix2);

    //boost single core computation finish

    //thrust computation start

    findCudaDevice(argc, (const char **)argv);

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    float alpha = 1.0f;
    float beta = 0.0f;

    auto result = cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, N, N, &alpha, matrix1.data().cbegin(), N, matrix2.data().cbegin(), N, &beta, zeroMatrix.data().begin(), N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceMatrix1(N*N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceMatrix2(N*N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceZeroMatrix(N*N, 0);

    thrust::copy(matrix1.data().cbegin(), matrix1.data().cend(), deviceMatrix1.begin());
    thrust::copy(matrix2.data().cbegin(), matrix2.data().cend(), deviceMatrix2.begin());

    auto result2 = cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, N, N, &alpha, deviceMatrix1.data().get(), N, deviceMatrix2.data().get(), N, &beta, deviceZeroMatrix.data().get(), N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    thrust::copy(deviceZeroMatrix.cbegin(), deviceZeroMatrix.cend(), zeroMatrix2.data().begin());

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << result2 << std::endl;

    //thrust computation finish    

    float eps = 0.00001;
    int differCount1 = 0;
    int differCount2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix3.size1(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix3.size2(); j++)
        {
            if (std::abs(matrix3(i, j) != zeroMatrix(i, j)) > eps)
                differCount1++;

            if (std::abs(matrix3(i, j) != zeroMatrix2(i, j)) > eps)
                differCount2++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << differCount1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << differCount2 << std::endl;

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

This file has name 'myFirstMatrixTest.cu'.

So, I have compilator errors:

> MSB3721   exit from command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -gencode=arch=compute_37,code=\"sm_37,compute_37\" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=\"sm_60,compute_60\" -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=\"sm_61,compute_61\" -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=\"sm_70,compute_70\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu
>   -rdc=true -I./ -I../common/inc -I../../common/inc -I/common/inc -I../ -I./ -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2/include" -I../../common/inc -I"C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include"  -G   --keep-dir
>   x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static
>   -Xcompiler "/wd 4819" -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MTd " -o
>   x64/Debug/MyFirstMatrixTest.cu.obj "C:\User Root\Repository\CUDA
>   Projects\MatrixMultiplicationThrust\MyFirstMatrixTest.cu"" with code
>   "2".  MyFirstMatrixTest   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   9.2.targets   707

and this:

> Fatal Error C1012 unmatched parenthesis : missing character
>   ")"   MyFirstMatrixTest   c:\local\boost\preprocessor\slot\detail\shared.hpp  27

Why could this error occur?

Thank you.

Comment: For thrust+boost to work you need to install a very specific version-combination of CUDA, visual studio and boost. Have you checked that?

Comment: @JHBonarius I've Installed CUDA 9.2 SDK, Boost and I have 2017 studio. Boost code (without any thrust code) works fine, thrust examples work fine too.

Comment: To test your code, I've updated my Cuda to v9.2 and now everything broke :'( So cannot help you until I fix it again. I had many issues trying to get the parts work together in the past. Heard it's a common problem.

Comment: I read up on this and found that nvcc has issues compiling boost code. You should probably separate your host and device code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first problem is

```
int N = 100000;
```

So N^2 = 10,000,000,000... (will never fit in an `int`). 
That is 10G*4 bytes(float) = 40 GBytes of data.
For me that throws a memory exception.

The next problem I had was with the combination of `unbounded_array` and `generate_n`. Just didn't work. But since you're using Thrust, use the Thrust types and algorithms (I'm not sure why Thrust has it's own types to replace STL, but whatever).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 v15.7 in 2015 mode (else I get a not supported error) with Cuda v9.2 and Boost 1.67.0.

I modified your code until it compiles correctly:
(Note the correction in the randomizer functor, it was first only generating integers and casting them to floats)

```
#include <boost/config/compiler/nvcc.hpp>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <cublas_v2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"cublas.lib")
#include <helper_cuda.h>

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
//#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
using boost::numeric::ublas::matrix;

#include <random>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    constexpr size_t N = 100;
    constexpr size_t NN = N * N;

    thrust::host_vector<float> lineMatrix1; lineMatrix1.reserve(NN);
    thrust::host_vector<float> lineMatrix2; lineMatrix2.reserve(NN);
    {
        std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
        std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
        std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(0.0f, 10.0f);
        auto genRnd = [&]() { return dis(gen); };
        thrust::generate_n(std::back_inserter(lineMatrix1), NN, genRnd);
        thrust::generate_n(std::back_inserter(lineMatrix2), NN, genRnd);
    }

    matrix<float> matrix1(N, N);
    thrust::copy_n(std::cbegin(lineMatrix1), NN, std::begin(matrix1.begin1()));
    //std::cout << "Matrix 1:\n" << matrix1 << std::endl;

    matrix<float> matrix2(N, N);
    thrust::copy_n(std::cbegin(lineMatrix2), NN, std::begin(matrix2.begin1()));
    //std::cout << "Matrix 2:\n" << matrix2 << std::endl;

    //auto matrix3 = prod(matrix1, matrix2);
    auto matrix3 = trans(prod(trans(matrix1), trans(matrix2)));
    //std::cout << "Matrix 3:\n" << matrix3 << std::endl;

    thrust::host_vector<float> hostResult; hostResult.reserve(NN);
    for (auto rowIt = matrix3.cbegin1(); rowIt != matrix3.cend1(); rowIt++)
        for (const auto& element : rowIt)
            hostResult.push_back(element);
    std::cout << "Host Result:\n";
    for (const auto& el : hostResult) std::cout << el << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //////boost single core computation finish

    //////thrust computation start
    findCudaDevice(argc, (const char **)argv);
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    const float alpha = 1.0f;
    const float beta = 0.0f;

    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceMatrix1; deviceMatrix1.reserve(NN);
    thrust::copy_n(std::cbegin(lineMatrix1), NN, std::back_inserter(deviceMatrix1));

    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceMatrix2; deviceMatrix2.reserve(NN);
    thrust::copy_n(std::cbegin(lineMatrix2), NN, std::back_inserter(deviceMatrix2));

    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceZeroMatrix(NN,0);
    auto result2 = cublasSgemm(handle,
        CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, N, N,
        &alpha,
        deviceMatrix1.data().get(), N,
        deviceMatrix2.data().get(), N,
        &beta,
        deviceZeroMatrix.data().get(), N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cublasDestroy(handle);

    thrust::host_vector<float> deviceResult; deviceResult.reserve(NN);
    thrust::copy_n(std::cbegin(deviceZeroMatrix), NN, std::back_inserter(deviceResult));
    std::cout << "Device Result:\n";
    for (const auto& el : deviceResult) std::cout << el << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //////thrust computation finish    

    auto accError = thrust::inner_product(std::cbegin(hostResult), std::cend(hostResult), std::cbegin(deviceResult), 0.0f, std::plus<float>(),
        [](auto val1, auto val2) { return std::abs(val1 - val2); });

    std::cout << "Accumulated error: " << accError << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average error: " << accError/NN << std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

edit: Fixed the code. ublas matrix stores the matrices different then vector, so I had to transpose the matrices and the result.
Furthermore, it turned out to be difficult to copy the ublas matrix back to a vector.

edit2: compilation parameters

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -x cu  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Cpp\Cuda\SoHelp2\kernel.cu"
```

Comment: Thxs for your code, man. I set up N=100000 like a "finger in a heaven" as russian say. So, of course, N should be much less than 100k. Also rand() isn't a good idea, I'll change this with algos from boost too. So, I have my pure boost code works fine in the independent project I've created for test. Also thrust has own standard algorithms realization which fully compatible with stl code (use the same syntx and so on). It's really better to use standard algos instead of handmade cycles. But, you've shown me the way to compile my code, thank you much!! I'll detect problems with code integration.

Comment: @Dmitriy I'm trying to learn boost/thrust/cuda myself, so it was a nice finger exercise. I wasn't familiar with the ublas `matrix` type, so I didn't know how to fill it using STD. For the randomizer I would normally use [std::uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Comment: @Dmitriy Got the code to work. The output error is much larger then you `eps`, so I made an accumulated error output. Please check it out.

Comment: I've tried to compile this code and got 101 errors.))) Possible, I need to take your compiler parameters. I changed version to 2015 in my Studio. It's 01:00 a.m. and I strongly need to sleep a little.))) Thank you, man, for your help!

Comment: @Dmitriy added compile cmd from visual studio. Strangly enough the include of the boost libraries is not shown and the CUDA libraries are included twice... The code will throw a couple of warnings by the way. Haven't found time to fix them.

Comment: you said that first time you tried to compile code, you had got ~100 errors. Could you explain your way of them elimination? Did you patch boost manually in the same ways? I can't do anything, damn. I gonna crazy!(((((

Comment: @Dmitriy I cannot if I don't have the errors. Please open a new question for that.

Comment: What was the actual reason for the original `missing character ")" ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using lambdas - feed the '--std=c++11' option to nvcc.

Comment: nvcc replied with "cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '--std=c++11'"

Comment: Yeah. I've tried to set up different types of standards - till 17. No results. Also I've added scl no warning to defeat checked iterators and additional directories for cl/cl.h and chrono lib. Also no result. So, just boost code compiles and works fine, but with thrust it can not be compiled... SFMBE(((

Comment: on windows `--std=c++11` is implicit with any recent version of  `nvcc`